# Listing of months with year december getting wrong year

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  //var date = "2017-04-06"
  //var date = "2017-01-06"
  $(".appendhere").empty();
  var date = $("option:selected",this).text();
  var monthnumber = date.split("-")[1] - 1;
  var yearnumber = date.split("-")[0];
  var months = 12;
  var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
    "October", "November", "December");
  for (var i = months - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var div = $('<div class="row" style="margin-top:6px;"><div class="col-md-6"><label class="col-md-6 col-form-label">' + yearnumber + " " + m_names[monthnumber] + '</label></div>');
    $(".appendhere").append(div)
    monthnumber == 11 ? monthnumber = 0 : monthnumber++;
    m_names[monthnumber] == "December" ? yearnumber++ : yearnumber + 0;
  }

}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>

<option>2017-04-06</option>
<option>2017-01-06</option>
</select>

<div class="appendhere"></div>
```

On change of select I want to append months with year based on the date of select.

I can add the month and year but the problem is the year for December is always 1 year ahead of the year.

I know it is small details but I cant point out where i did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute `"January"` for `"December"` at conditional operator.

```
m_names[monthnumber] == "January" ? yearnumber++ : yearnumber + 0;
```

Comment: believe me tried this one but it didnt work. now i think the problem is with my browser i have to always clear the cashe so that js will update. why is that happening although this is different question

Comment: i change it to january refresh the page it didnt work same 2018 now i tried to clear browsing history first it worked.. this is the cause of problem not the code i was foolish to realize it before this answer. it is like i need to clear browsing history so that js will load properly. why is this?

Comment: @Pekka Have you tried disabling browser cache at `DevTools` `Network` -> check `Disable cache`? See https://jsfiddle.net/cdkz1ssr/

Comment: @Pekka - Have you tried a "hard refresh" by pressing Ctrl-F5 rather than just F5? Sometimes that does it without the hassle of clearing the whole cache.

Comment: i see i will try those what i usually do to refresh is just click the circle arrow or enter on url..

Answer (score 1):

Reverse these two lines:

```
monthnumber == 11 ? monthnumber = 0 : monthnumber++;
m_names[monthnumber] == "December" ? yearnumber++ : yearnumber + 0;
```

You're currently incrementing the month *before* testing whether the year should change.

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  //var date = "2017-04-06"
  //var date = "2017-01-06"
  $(".appendhere").empty();
  var date = $("option:selected",this).text();
  var monthnumber = date.split("-")[1] - 1;
  var yearnumber = date.split("-")[0];
  var months = 12;
  var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
    "October", "November", "December");
  for (var i = months - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var div = $('<div class="row" style="margin-top:6px;"><div class="col-md-6"><label class="col-md-6 col-form-label">' + yearnumber + " " + m_names[monthnumber] + '</label></div>');
    $(".appendhere").append(div)
    m_names[monthnumber] == "December" ? yearnumber++ : yearnumber + 0;
    monthnumber == 11 ? monthnumber = 0 : monthnumber++;        
  }

}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>

<option>2017-04-06</option>
<option>2017-01-06</option>
</select>

<div class="appendhere"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have increased `monthnumber` before check its name `m_names[monthnumber] == "December" ?`.

You should change the order of 2 below line of code:

From:

```
monthnumber == 11 ? monthnumber = 0 : monthnumber++; 
m_names[monthnumber] == "December" ? yearnumber++ : yearnumber + 0;
```

To:

```
m_names[monthnumber] == "December" ? yearnumber++ : yearnumber + 0;
monthnumber == 11 ? monthnumber = 0 : monthnumber++;
```

```js
$("select").change(function() {
  //var date = "2017-04-06"
  //var date = "2017-01-06"
  $(".appendhere").empty();
  var date = $("option:selected",this).text();
  var monthnumber = date.split("-")[1] - 1;
  var yearnumber = date.split("-")[0];
  var months = 12;
  var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
    "October", "November", "December");
  for (var i = months - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var div = $('<div class="row" style="margin-top:6px;"><div class="col-md-6"><label class="col-md-6 col-form-label">' + yearnumber + " " + m_names[monthnumber] + '</label></div>');
    $(".appendhere").append(div)       
    m_names[monthnumber] == "December" ? yearnumber++ : yearnumber + 0;
    monthnumber == 11 ? monthnumber = 0 : monthnumber++;
  }

}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>

<option>2017-04-06</option>
<option>2017-01-06</option>
</select>

<div class="appendhere"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

reverse the last two line dude

```
monthnumber == 11 ? monthnumber = 0 : monthnumber++; 
m_names[monthnumber] == "December" ? yearnumber++ : yearnumber + 0;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sa6onxgc/3/

Comment: How is Answer different from this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42570890/)?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work.

```
     for (var i = months -1; i >= 0; i--) {
         monthnumber == 11 ? monthnumber = 0 : monthnumber++;
         var div = $('<div class="row" style="margin-top:6px;"><div class="col-md-6"><label class="col-md-6 col-form-label">' + yearnumber + " " + m_names[monthnumber] + '</label></div>');
         $(".appendhere").append(div)
         m_names[monthnumber] == "December" ? yearnumber++ : yearnumber + 0;
      }
```